# Redirect to another page after login

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redirect

I'm working on a project in React and ran into a problem that has me stumped.

I want to redirect to Google page when ever user successfully login and i don't know how to redirect on another page

so here is my code and i am not able to redirect to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).

if any one have some solution it will be really great if you help me

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import url from "../ApiCall";
import Dashboard from "../DashBoard/Dashboard";
import LoginForm from "./LoginForm";
import styles from "../../styles/style.css";

export class Login extends Component {
    state = {
        status: "",
    };

    submitForm = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let form = event.target;
        let formObj = {
            email: form.email.value,
            password: form.password.value,
        };
        fetch(`${url}users/login`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            mode: "cors",
            body: JSON.stringify(formObj),
        })
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.data) {
                    this.setState({ status: "Successful" });
                    form.reset();
                    alert("Login Successfully");
                } else {
                    console.error();
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                alert(`${form.email.value}, Please try again :)`);
                alert(err);
                console.log(err);
            });
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                {this.state.status === "Successful" ? (
                    /*Redirect to www.google.com*/
                ) : (
                    <form onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
                        <LoginForm />
                        <div className={styles["footer"]}>
                            <button type="submit" value="submit" className="btn">
                                Login
                            </button>
                            <button type="reset" value="reset" className="btn">
                                Reset
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                )}
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

if anyone have solution please tell me

Comment: Did you use react-router-dom?

Comment: @zahrazamani no i haven't define route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use React Router DOM, you can simply return `<Redirect to="google.com" />` component. Or you can do `history.push('google.com');`

Comment: where to use history.push()

Comment: Create it from useHistory() hook. Here's an [example](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks). But I'd go for Redirect component.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
    import url from "../ApiCall";
    import Dashboard from "../DashBoard/Dashboard";
    import LoginForm from "./LoginForm";
    import styles from "../../styles/style.css";
    import { Route , withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
    class Login extends Component {
        state = {
            status: "",
        };
    
        submitForm = (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            let form = event.target;
            let formObj = {
                email: form.email.value,
                password: form.password.value,
            };
            fetch(`${url}users/login`, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                mode: "cors",
                body: JSON.stringify(formObj),
            })
                .then((response) => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data.data) {
                        this.setState({ status: "Successful" });
                        form.reset();
                        alert("Login Successfully");
                    } else {
                        console.error();
                    }
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    alert(`${form.email.value}, Please try again :)`);
                    alert(err);
                    console.log(err);
                });
        };
        render() {
            return (
                <>
                    {this.state.status === "Successful" ? (
                       this.props.history.push({
                            pathname: "www.google.com",
                          
                        })
                    ) : (
                        <form onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
                            <LoginForm />
                            <div className={styles["footer"]}>
                                <button type="submit" value="submit" className="btn">
                                    Login
                                </button>
                                <button type="reset" value="reset" className="btn">
                                    Reset
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    )}
                </>
            );
        }
    }
export default withRouter(Login) ;
```